# How to calculate negative numbers on calculator problem using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have written a basic program to do arithmetic operations, where the user input will be in a single line containing two integers and operator(+, -, *, /, and %) similar to `3 + 5`.
I have written this code so far it works for all positive integers but when I try to give a negative integer it throws `IndexError`

```
def calculator(given_input):
    cal = []
    
    def operation(given_input):
        int_input = given_input.split()
        for i in int_input:
            if i.isdigit():
                cal.append(int(i))

    #for addition            
    if ("+" in given_input):
        operation(given_input)
        print(cal[0] + cal[1])
    #for subraction
    if ("-" in given_input):
        operation(given_input)
        print(cal[0] - cal[1])
    #for division
    if ("/" in given_input):
        operation(given_input)
        print(cal[0] - cal[1])
    #for multiplication
    if ("*" in given_input):
        operation(given_input)
        print(cal[0] * cal[1])
    #for modulous
    if ("%" in given_input):
        operation(given_input)
        print(cal[0] % cal[1])
    
        
given_input = input()
calculator(given_input)
```

Comment: what does `'-5'.isdigit()` return? It is not considered a digit by python's `isdigit`.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Hint: What's in `cal` when you give a negative integer? Why does that happen?

Comment: `isdigit` is a test for character types, not for whether a string can be interpreted as a number. `isdigit` is almost never the correct tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the supposition you make that each element is space-separated, (not like `3+4`) as you used `given_input.split()` that splits on space, you can directly use the index of that element. Also don't call `operation` in each branch, call it before or better just execute the code directly

```py
def calculator(given_input):
    cal = []

    int_input = given_input.split()
    cal.append(int(int_input[0]))
    cal.append(int(int_input[2]))

    if "+" == int_input[1]:
        print(cal[0] + cal[1])
    elif "-" == int_input[1]:
        print(cal[0] - cal[1])
    elif "/" == int_input[1]:
        print(cal[0] - cal[1])
    elif "*" == int_input[1]:
        print(cal[0] * cal[1])
    elif "%" == int_input[1]:
        print(cal[0] % cal[1])
```

---

To handle multiple situations, with spaced or non-spaced content, use a regular expression with `re` module, a regex like `(-?\d+)\s*([+-/*%])\s*(-?\d+)`

- `(-?\d+)` a possible minus, then an amount of digit
- `\s*` a posible amount of spaces
- `([+-/*%])` any char in these 5 `+-/*%`
- `\s*` a posible amount of spaces
- `(-?\d+)` a possible minus, then an amount of digit

```py
import re

def calculator(given_input):
    int_input = re.search("(-?\d+)\s*([+-/*%])\s*(-?\d+)", given_input)
    if not int_input:
        print("Format error of '", int_input, "'")
        return

    a, operator, b = int_input.groups()
    a, b = int(a), int(b)

    if "+" == operator:
        print(a + b)
    elif "-" == operator:
        print(a - b)
    elif "/" == operator:
        print(a / b)
    elif "*" == operator:
        print(a * b)
    elif "%" == operator:
        print(a % b)
```

Comment: Great explanation, Thank you azro.